# Using IF operator in Visual Basic 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I can code the following problem in Visual Basic 2008 using the IF-THEN-ELSE structure. But I want to know how to code it using the IF operator in Visual Basic 2008.

Write a program that requests 3 numbers as input and displays the sum of the two highest numbers.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't sound like you need an `If` at all.  Request the three inputs, store them in a collection, order the collection ascending, skip 1 element, sum the rest of the elements, display the sum.

Comment: But I want to know how to use IF operator, other than IF-THEN-ELSE structure

Comment: Then either ask your teacher for guidance or a hint, or show what you've tried with your IF-THEN-ELSE structure and what didn't work with an IF structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really must use an `If`, you could adapt @David or @Gerino idea:

```
    Dim inputs(2) As Integer

    For index = 0 To 2
        inputs(index) = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine)
    Next

    If True Then
        Console.Write(inputs.OrderByDescending(Function(f) f).Take(2).Sum())
    End If

    Console.ReadLine()
```

or if you want to demonstrate knowledge of the short-circuited `If` syntax:

```
    Dim inputs(2) As Integer

    For index = 0 To 2
        inputs(index) = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine)
    Next

    Dim totalSum As Integer = inputs.OrderByDescending(Function(f) f).Take(2).Sum()
    Dim output As String = If(totalSum > 0, "Positive: " & totalSum, "Negative:" & totalSum)

    Console.Write(output)
    Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: I'm looking for the following type. If( [argument1,] argument2, argument3 )

Answer (score 0):

Besides standard answer ("Pick up a decent general programming book"): if the task is stated as you have put it - that is, there are no restrictions or guidelines - you don't need IFs at all. It can be done in one line using LINQ:

```
Dim numbers As List(Of Integer)
    numbers = New List(Of Integer)

    numbers.Add(9)
    numbers.Add(-4)
    numbers.Add(1)

    Console.WriteLine(numbers.OrderByDescending(Function(n) n).Take(2).Sum())
```

You can read into numbers for example using for loop (from 1 to 3).

EDIT BELOW

If you are to specifically use IF statements, but not ELSE statements (that's how I understand your question/comment), it's basically a general computer science excersise, not a programming problem ;) But anyway (I'll use C syntax because it's easier for me to write in it, sorry):

You have 3 numbers, (x,y,z). Using relation >= (greater or equal) they can be arranged in 6 (3!, three factorial) ways:

```
x, y, z
x, z, y
y, x, z
y, z, x
z, x, y
z, y, x
```

Now, in most languages you cannot unfortunately use statements like:

```
if(x >= y >= z)
```

but you can split it into

```
if(x >= y && y >= z)
```

That gives you a way to execute only a specific code block in each of possible scenarios:

```
if(x >= y && y >= z){
    // biggest numbers: x, y
    return x + y;
}
if(x >= z && z >= y){
...and so on, 6 times total
```

Note, that this is a naive approach, and it is not the best solution. If you're in a hurry, it will do. If you have time to spare, you can think of more optimal solutions - as an exercise ;)

Comment: Since I'm new to Visual Basic, my teacher ask to do it using IF operator. How can I do that? Please help me